# Capturar Imagen GD con JQuery

Tags: jquery, laravel, imagen, gd

Estoy armando un sistema en laravel que retorna una imágen al ingresar a una URL.

Esa imágen se genera en tiempo real según el ID enviado en la URL... y quiero que otras personas puedan poner en su página web esa imágen dinámica.

Mi Controller es:

```
public function APITest(Request $request, $id, $slug)
    {


        $img = Image::make(public_path('images/default.png'));  
       $img->text('Total Data ' . $data->count() , 250, 100, function($font) {  
          $font->file(public_path('path/font.ttf'));  
          $font->size(28);  
          $font->color('#000000');  
          $font->align('center');  
          $font->valign('bottom');  
          $font->angle(0);  
      });  


       return $img->response('jpg');
    }
```

Cuando ingreso a la url localhost/api/1/test con el navegador

```
Route::get('{id}/{slug}', 'SiteController@APITest')->name('api.test');
```

Puedo ver la imagen con su correspondiente texto y funciona todo a la perfección.

Ahora donde tengo el problema es en el siguiente apartado:

Mostrar esta imágen en la web de un 3ero.

Yo quiero que mis usuarios coloquen este embeded en sus webs:

```
<div id="testLoad"></div>

<script>$("#testLoad").load("http://localhost/api/company/1/servertest");</script>
```

y les muestre la imágen.

pero en su lugar les muestra:

```
����JFIF``��;CREATOR: gd-jpeg v1.0 (using IJG JPEG v90), quality = 90 ��C     ��C    ���X"�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?��ه�a�Ư�����kwo��d���FQb��!�c��{�W���|=��ω��*���Q����=7������m�����G�0������������_�3�o� ��������Q�G�0������������_�3�o� �����s0�G���_�3�o� ����|=��ω��*���W��Q�Õ4�|=��ω��*���Q�����>&����1_K�G3T|������>&����1G�0����������}/E�9Q�G�0������������_�3�o� �����s0�G���_�3�o� ����|=��ω��*���W��Q�Õ4�|=��ω��*���Q�����>&����1_K�G3T|������>&����1G�0����������}/E�9Q�G�0���������
```

Comment: de casualidad no sera que tiene algun problema de encoding? mete el embed en un archivo `.html` y habrelo desde el escritorio a ver que sucede?

Comment: Hola, solucionado! estaba enfocandolo mal.

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado,

```
<div id="imageContainer"></div>


<script>
    $('#imageContainer').html('<img src="http://localhost/api/company/1/servertest" />');
</script>
```

Terminé implementando el [`.html`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) para insertar el código completo del tag IMG colocando su ruta.

Comment: muy bien, buena respuesta